# type casting float value of log2() to int, odd result

Tags: floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%f\n", log2((unsigned)~0));       /* float size of int */
  printf("%d\n", (int)log2((unsigned)~0));  /* will not convert to int */
}
```

This returns 32.000000 and 31! why not 32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your program slightly:

```
printf("%.16e\n", log2((unsigned)~0));       /* float size of int */
```

And it shows:

```
3.1999999999664098e+01
31
```

So the answer to “why it converts to 31” is that `log2((unsigned)~0)` is between 31 and 32, as you can expect knowing that `~(unsigned)0` is slightly less than 2<sup>32</sup>.

Another question is “why does the floating-point number `3.1999999999664098e+01` print as `32.000000`?”. The answer to that is “What else would you have liked it to print as? 32.000000 is the closest decimal representation with 6 digits after the dot to the actual floating-point value.”